# Adding two variables with subscripts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

What is the explanation to why $x_{3k} + x_{3k+1}$, is equal to $x_{3k+2}$. Isn't that incorrect because there is no value 1 in the subscript $x_{3k}$?

I saw this in a prove in http://www2.math.ou.edu/~aroche/courses/2513-Sp2012/solutions5.pdf that proves that $f_{3n}$ is an even number.

Also is there a certain area of math the subscript algebra falls under? I would like to go in depth with the topic

Comment: In general, there is no 'subscript algebra', and patterns which you observe there are a result of how the sequence is defined against the indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "subscript algebra" in general, as @jameselmore writes. There is such an algebra in specific cases, and problem 4 in the problem set in your link is such a case.

In problem 4, the sequence is the *Fibonacci sequence*, which is given by

$$f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2} \text { for }n>2$$

If you replace $n$ in that equation with $3k+2$ and $f_n$ with $x_k$, you get your equation $x_{3k}+x_{3k+1}=x_{3k+2}$. This is not true in general, but it is for the Fibonacci sequence.

You may want to study the Fibonacci numbers in depth. Do a web search on the phrase and you will get more than you can handle. There is even a journal, ["The Fibonacci Quarterly"](http://www.fq.math.ca/), that studies only that and related topics.